# Trying to read commits from azure devops rest api results in redirects

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

I am trying to get a list of commits. The execution waits forever on getting repoResponse.

Why?

When I paste the url (getting it from hovering repoUri in visual studio), I am never prompted for a basic auth password but I get redirected to a login page.

```
public async Task ListCommits()
{
    var pat = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PAT"];
    var encodedPat = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($":{pat}"));

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", encodedPat);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var repoUri = $"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repository}?api-version=6.0";
        var repoResponse = await client.GetAsync(repoUri);
        if (!repoResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to retrieve repository. Status code: {repoResponse.StatusCode}");
            return;
        }

        string repoResponseContent = await repoResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var repo = JObject.Parse(repoResponseContent);
        var repoId = repo["id"].ToString();

        var commitsUri = $"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repoId}/commits?searchCriteria.itemVersion.version=master&api-version=6.0";
        var commitsResponse = await client.GetAsync(commitsUri);
        if (!commitsResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to retrieve commits. Status code: {commitsResponse.StatusCode}");
            return;
        }

        string commitsContent = await commitsResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Commits Response:");
        Console.WriteLine(commitsContent);

        var commitsData = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(commitsContent);
        foreach (var commit in commitsData["value"])
        {
            var commitId = commit["commitId"].ToString();
            var changesUri = $"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repoId}/commits/{commitId}/changes?api-version=6.0";
            var changesResponse = await client.GetAsync(changesUri);
            if (changesResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string changesContent = await changesResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"Changes for Commit ID {commitId}:");
                Console.WriteLine(changesContent);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to retrieve changes for commit {commitId}. Status code: {changesResponse.StatusCode}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## curl

I also tried to use curl to fetch the repoUri. Organization and Project and TheRepo are actually something else.

```
curl -u :theencodepath= https://dev.azure.com/Organization/Project/_apis/git/repositories/TheRepo?api-version=6.0
```

The result starts like:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://spsprodeus21.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signin?realm=de
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code sample, you are using the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PAT"]` to read the PAT from the app.config file.

If the PAT token doesn't exists, it will redirect to a login page.

I can reproduce the same issue when using the same code sample.

[image]

To solve this issue, you need to add an app.config file to your project.

For example:

[image]

Then you can add the PAT value to the app.config file.

For example:

```
<configuration>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="PAT" value="PAT Token Value"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

When you run the C# Project, it will read the PAT from the app.config file and run the Rest API to get the commits.

**Result:**

[image]

**Update:**

Full sample code:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    class Program

    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pat = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PAT"];
            var encodedPat = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($":{pat}"));

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", encodedPat);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                var repoUri = $"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{reponame}?api-version=6.0";
                var repoResponse = await client.GetAsync(repoUri);
                if (!repoResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Failed to retrieve repository. Status code: {repoResponse.StatusCode}");
                    return;
                }

                string repoResponseContent = await repoResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var repo = JObject.Parse(repoResponseContent);
                var repoId = repo["id"].ToString();

                var commitsUri = $"https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{Project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repoId}/commits?searchCriteria.itemVersion.version=master&api-version=6.0";
                var commitsResponse = await client.GetAsync(commitsUri);
                if (!commitsResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Failed to retrieve commits. Status code: {commitsResponse.StatusCode}");
                    return;
                }

                string commitsContent = await commitsResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Commits Response:");
                Console.WriteLine(commitsContent);

                var commitsData = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(commitsContent);
                foreach (var commit in commitsData["value"])
                {
                    var commitId = commit["commitId"].ToString();
                    var changesUri = $"https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/git/repositories/{repoId}/commits/{commitId}/changes?api-version=6.0";
                    var changesResponse = await client.GetAsync(changesUri);
                    if (changesResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string changesContent = await changesResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine($"Changes for Commit ID {commitId}:");
                        Console.WriteLine(changesContent);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Failed to retrieve changes for commit {commitId}. Status code: {changesResponse.StatusCode}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update2:**

Refer to this doc to create PAT: [Use personal access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows)

[image]

Comment: I already have app.config with the pat and it shows up when I am debugging. Do I have to check if it is valid? I could also try to alter it slightly and see if I get the same result.

Comment: @AndersLindén Yes. You also need to check if the PAT is valid. If the PAT is not valid, it will also return the login page. Usually returning to the login interface means authentication failed.

Comment: What bugs me is that the function never returns, not even if I use `var handler = new HttpClientHandler(); handler.AllowAutoRedirect = false; var client = new HttpClient(handler)`

Comment: I tested the same function as your code. And it can return the value successfully. Can you try to directly input the PAT in the main code(without app.config file)? For example: `var pat ="PAT VALUE";`

Comment: I have updated my answer to share the full sample code. You can check it and have a try

Comment: I managed to get an error message now that sais unauthorized. Does that mean that I am confusing pats? Are there multiple kinds of pats? I did create it on `https://tfs.organization.com/tfs/org/_usersSettings/tokens`
that url being somewhat modified.

Comment: Yes. I think you may use different PAT. You can refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows to create a Personal access token to authenticate the rest api. You can create a **full access** PAT for test.

Comment: At the same time, from the URL you shared, are you running the c# to get the repo from Azure DevOps Server instead of Azure DevOps Service?

Comment: I am not sure what to answer, but I will try to use the api to get that pat, maybe its not really a good thing to store it in app.config if it is short lived then?

Comment: @AndersLindén To create PAT, you can directly do it on the Azure DevOps Site. You can set the expired date. Its expiration time is customized and is not very short.

Comment: If you are using Azure DevOps Service, you can navigate to site: `https://dev.azure.com/organizationname/_usersSettings/tokens` and create a full access PAT.

Comment: That took me to a page saying 401 - Uh-oh, you do not have access.

Comment: If you get 401 error when accessing the PAT site, you can try to use Browser InPrivate Window. And you need to use your organization name to replace the organization name in the URL. `https://dev.azure.com/{yourorganizationname}/_usersSettings/tokens`

Comment: @AndersLindén May I know if you can generate a valid PAT and use it to run the C# project now? Feel free to let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I was able to use the PAT I already have, the error as elsewhere!

Comment: @AndersLindén Are you using Azure DevOps Cloud Service or Azure DevOps On-prem server? If you are using Azure DevOps Server the Rest API URL should be different.